# I unintentionally said Jesus is Lord

Tags: allah

One day I accidentally said Jesus is Lord but then I immediately asked  for forgiveness and even retoke my shahada but even after all that I still worry Allah(SWT) hasn’t forgiven.I still want to ask will I be forgiven

Answer (score 1):

There is no blame on someone who does a sin out of ignorance to the ruling or out of forgetfulness.

- *It was narrated from Ibn 'Abbas that the Prophet (ﷺ) said :
  "Allah has forgiven my nation for mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do."*

[See reference here](https://sunnah.com/urn/1321240)

so there is nothing to worry about Insha Allah.

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum and jazakallah khayrun for your question

We should never lose hope of Allah's mercy for it is greater than any sin we could ever commit, and that is even the same ruling for someone who commits shirk intentionally but then regret their sin, repent to Allah and do everything to stay away from that sin.

So for someone who does it unintentionally they are even more likely to get the forgiveness of Allah

Talking of those that commit sins intentionally, including shirk; interpretation of the meaning:
“Say: ‘O ‘Ibaadi (My slaves) who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allaah, verily, Allaah forgives all sins. Truly, He is Oft‑Forgiving, Most Merciful’” [al-Zumar 39:53]

Someone doesn't get forgiven if they die in the state of shirk but if they commit shirk and then regret what they did and turn to Allah in repentance changing their ways for the best while doing everything to stay away from that sin, Allah will then forgive them. Alhamdulillah

His mercy is such that He will even turn their bad deeds into good deeds in shaa Allah.

Qu'ran 12:87 And do not lose hope in the mercy of Allah; indeed none lose hope in the mercy of Allah except the most ungrateful people

And Allah knows best